# Customised Incoming call screen

Tags: android

I am trying to add few views to the incoming call screen with required functionality.
Is it possible to do overide the exis android OS call screen? 
Is there any way to achieve this as stand alone application.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got simple solution

Please see below link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread/9462119#9462119

Answer (score 0):

I think incoming call activity have high priority that is set by the linux in kernel level. you have to set high priority to render your screen then incoming call activity will be in background. it use concept of intent and intent filter.

given links will help to understand intent and intent filter

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html