# Incoming call is blocked on emulator by using aidl but it gives fatal exception on mobile phone

Tags: android

I want to abort an incoming call. It works on the emulator but on the mobile phone it gives an exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main -
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10076 nor current 
process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.
```

What should I do for this?

Comment: i m included the android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission but the exception is still coming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Android 2.3+ (Gingerbread) you can't solve this problem: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the permission `android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) for details.
And here is the [list of permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).