# why 2.3 version of android does not hava android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE ? and what is the solution for this?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to grant MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission for apps ran on Gingerbread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread)

i want to abort a call but i m getting an error that: Neither user 10076 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.

i am also give the permission in manifest for that but i found that android 2.3 is not giving the permission for MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.

so pls give any better solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at [How to grant MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission for apps ran on Gingerbread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread)

Comment: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission is no longer working on silenceRinger() since 2.3+, but endCall is just fine. So the solution is to comment out the call to silenceRinger().