# How to not fire PhoneStateListener.CALL_STATE_RINGING if already talking and a second caller is calling

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am programming an app, that automatically answers a call. The problem is, that it should not answer one if I am already in a call and someone is ringing.
Is there a way to achieve that?

According to the doc, if I check the status with `TelephonyManager` it would be `CALL_STATE_RINGING` and not `CALL_STATE_OFFTHEHOOK`.

Do I have to add a variable that is set true on a changing Telephone state so I know that there is an ongoing call or is there a better solution?

Thanks!

/edit: I answer the call without the permission `Modify_Phone_State`, so it is only about finding out if there is already a call ongoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so as there is apparently no way to figure this out, I stored a Boolean in a SharedPreference as soon as the State goes to `OFFTHEHOOK` (true).

When the state changes to `IDLE`, I set the Boolean to false. So this means, if `RINGING` is fired while someone is already calling, I read out that the variable is true, and then discard the following actions.

For those who want more information on how to answer a call, have a look at the [AutoAnswer Project](http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/)

Answer (score 1):

Tracking call state seams the best way, because your question is off the track of android standard.

There is no official answer to your question because :

By the Android API there is no official way for a third party application provider to answer to a phone call because 
1 : you've to use undocumented API.
2 : request MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission is only available for rooted/system signed application since 2.3

So if an efficient(build in code) working answer exist for your question, it may officially not working for every manufacturer/model devices.

more info at [How to grant MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission for apps ran on Gingerbread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread)

Comment: Actually I am not using the Modify_Phone_State permission, but emulating a bluetooth headset kepress that answers the call without a permission in the android manifest ;-)

Comment: Nice trick! In my answer I didn't expect this kind of way to hang up/down a phone call ..