# Send a mobile number from default android dialer to my application

Tags: android

I have a application for calling an API for phone call,
When a user dials a number from default dialer of android phone, the number should be copied into the second app(free call twilio),shown in picture.

[image]

Here is what I tried, but no luck.

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Can anyone help please? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be possible after searching a lot in google. Finally I got an answer I am sharing it for others.

It can be possible by adding following intent filter in manifest file.

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

please use below code

Register a BroadcastReceiver like this in Manifest file:

```
    <!-- DIAL Receiver -->
    <receiver
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="receivers.DialBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

You need Permission for NEW_OUTGOING_CALL :

```
<!-- OUTGOING CALL PERMISSION-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

public class DialBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.v("DileBroadCastReceiver","In onReceive()");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
         String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

         Log.v("DialBroadcast Receiver","Number is: "+number);

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Sanket I want to pass dialed number to myApp after choose my Application

Comment: yes, you can get in this Log.v("DialBroadcast Receiver","Number is: "+number);

Comment: Broadcast Receiver execute after starting the call. I want make call from MyApp through VoIp API(Like Skype)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add intent-filter in your mainActivty like below

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
```

also add your existing intent-filter as well. Gud luck

Answer (score -1):

create a broadcast reciever with android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL and then call
 dialledNumber=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

This will give you outgoing number

try this.it might help

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: I want to make call from my application. Your suggested answer is for read number after making call from SIM card.

Comment: I think you should call the default application for making call for you.

Comment: Yes I am calling my application but cant able to pass dialed number to that application

Comment: the edit if for passing the number from your application to the default application

Comment: Actually I want pass number dialpad to my App. and you suggest me exactly reverse solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267411/make-or-receive-call-secretly-programmatically-android  check this link.

Comment: I think you are not getting my question. I dont want to call problematically. I have to show dialed number after choose default app i.e. free call twilio (shown in Image)

Comment: sorry I wont be able to answer that.Sorry for wasting your time