# Trap incoming call and hit a web service and display a response on "call receive reject panel" of Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-widget, telephony

I want to create an android app which will do the following

1. Traps/listens to an incoming call event ( im aware this step may have  duplicates on SO but for the sake of completeness, im asking)
2. Takes over the control and hits a web service ( HTTP POST ) to get some info from the internet
3. And display the same as an "alert widget" on top of a "call receive/reject buttons", usually a place where we get "face" of the contact.

basic question is , is it feasible to develop such an app on stock android  ? if yes , how ?
What are the consequences , if any ?

The solution should work on latest Android releases as well ( 2.3 onwards, 2.3 had a controversial patch which broke may apps relying on private telephony api of android )

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html states that,

> In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from
>   within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the
>   NotificationManager API. For the latter, you can use
>   Context.startService() to send a command to the service.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1) part you can create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and listen for the

> TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED action.

This will handle your call event.

For the 2) part to need to write an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that performs the [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) action to your webservice. There are many tutorials available on the web on how to go about doing the HttpPost action.

Now, whenever you implement an AsyncTask, you have a [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) method. Inside that method you can do your 3rd part of displaying using the Alert Dialog.

Hope it helps,

All the best

Cheers

Comment: Does it work with Android 2.3 ( and latest ) onwards ? 

I have gone through lot of SO debates and other on line materials which refers to a problematic patch on a private telephony api which allows only system apps to gain access to the kind of use case we have ?

Comment: Yes, your right Android 2.3 has certain issues. I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread . But anyways you can try it on Android 2.2 first, till then the issues will be resolved :)