# Unregister BroadcastReceiver in IntentService

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I'm new to Android development.  I am trying to develop a widget with a button that toggles whether the device automatically answers incoming calls.

I started by created a class that extends AppWidgetProvider.  I'm using SharedPreferences to store the state of the widget button.  In the OnReceive(Context, Intent) method, I am using an intent to start an IntentService that registers a BroadcastReceiver to listen for changes the phone state.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to unregister the BroadcastReceiver when the widget has been toggled off -- my code continues to monitor the phone state no matter the state of the widget button. Is it possible?  Or is there another way that I can stop the PhoneStateListener?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Here are the revisions to the code

Manifest: I put the BroadcastReceiver with the android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE intent-filter in the manifest

In the AppWidgetProvider:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver.class);

//use to enable the broadcast receiver
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

//use to disable the broadcast receiver
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

In the BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //check call state
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(tm.getCallState()==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
        try{

            //wait 2 seconds then answer the call
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);
            telephony.silenceRinger();
            telephony.answerRingingCall();

        } catch(Exception e){}
    }

}
```

Don't need a PhoneStateListener...

Bummer that [this won't work on 2.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using an intent to start an IntentService that registers a BroadcastReceiver to listen for changes the phone state

This will not work reliably, as once the `IntentService` exits, your process may terminate and your `BroadcastReceiver` will go away. Please put the phone state `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest.

> However, I can't seem to figure out how to unregister the BroadcastReceiver when the widget has been toggled off

Use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to enable or disable the phone state receiver you place in the manifest.

Also, you cannot reliably do anything from a `BroadcastReceiver` that lives past `onReceive()`, such as register an event listener, as you are doing here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I got rid of the dynamically registered receiver and put it in the manifest instead, and I used setComponentEnabledSetting to control the receiver, as you suggested.  I'm still having some issues with the event listener, but I moved it out of the BroadcastReceiver and I will probably be able to figure it out from there.