# Turn off/on cell radio on jelly bean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, cellular-network, airplane-mode

Is there any way to disable the cell antenna in android 4.2 and up? I need to be able to disable it from my application. My current implementation works until 4.1, using the airplane mode, but as I found out now, airplane mode can't be changed without root permission in the latest jelly bean releases.

Do you have any solution to this?

Regards,
Cristian

Comment: Are you trying to disable cellular data?  If so you can [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970729/how-to-change-the-network-state-of-device-from-source-code-in-android).

Comment: no, to disconnect the phone from the network.