# connecting android emulators using tcp sockets

Tags: android, android-asynctask, tcpsocket

the following is my code. Editor: Eclipse, Platform: Windows.

Its a chat application where 2 android emulators connect through a tcp socket.

UI consists of a send button, a text view and a text box.

Problem: As soon as I type text and hit send, the application crashes.

server port is 8000.
So my redirection is redir add tcp:8081:8000 and redir add tcp:8082:8000.

I donno what is wrong in my code. Please suggest me somthing I need to change.

```
public class HelloandroidActivity extends Activity 
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public int serverport=8000;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);             
   final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
   Integer severport=8000;
   new Server().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,severport);
   button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
          final String name = nameField.getText().toString();
          final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          //tv.setText(name);

          String s=null;

        new Client().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,s);
     } 
          });// end onclicklis  

     }//end oncreate



 class Server extends AsyncTask <Integer, String, String>
{
public InetAddress byIpAsName ;
int r=0;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Integer... serverport)  {
    //i[0]=serverport;
    Integer[] sp=serverport;
    BufferedReader in=null;
    ServerSocket s=null;
     r=sp[0];
    String cIn="";
    try {
        //byIpAsName = InetAddress.getByName("10.2.2.15");
        s=new ServerSocket(r);
    while(true)
    {
        Socket client = s.accept();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String line=in.readLine();
        cIn=null;
        while(line!=null){cIn=cIn.concat(line);}

    }//while    

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        s.close();
        in.close();
        } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cIn;


}//end inBackground
//@SuppressWarnings("null")
protected void onPostExecute(String... cIn)
{

  }//onpost execute

  }//server class
    public class Client extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
     PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in=null;
    String sIn=null;
     //Server s1=new Server();
    //int q=s1.r;
    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String portStr = tel.getLine1Number().substring(tel.getLine1Number().length() - 4);
    int q = Integer.parseInt(portStr);
   Socket socket;
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   try 
   {
     //q=8080;
     InetAddress byIpAsName1=InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
     socket = new Socket(byIpAsName1, q);
     out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
     in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
     String line=in.readLine();
      sIn=null;
     while(line!=null){sIn=sIn.concat(line);}
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }//catch
   return sIn;
    }//in background
    protected void onPostExecute(String... sIn)
    {
    String c=null;
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   c=c.concat(sIn[0]);
   tv.setText(c);
    }
     }  

  }//main class
```

Comment: can you post the logcat of the error?

Comment: @John, thanks for responding.. the below link is the logcat

Comment: https://docs.google.com/a/buffalo.edu/document/d/10VFYUL94revSdxSxrCmGnOFTZRNqvu7rdu1bx0iCAPY/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logcat, what is important is this line:

```
03-16 23:12:23.434: E/AndroidRuntime(571): java.lang.SecurityException: Requires READ_PHONE_STATE: Neither user 10040 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
```

This indicates that in order to run your code, you need the READ_PHONE_STATE permission in the android manifest.xml.

Add this line to the manifest, outside of the `<application>` tag but inside the `<manifest>` tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

If this does not solve the issue, the problem could be related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5095956/342745).

Comment: If my answer is correct, don't forget to accept it by clicking the green checkmark (you'll get rep)!  Also, if you think an answer or question is helpful, you can also upvote it by clicking the up arrow to the left.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Hi John, Here is the new logcat, i dont know what exactly is going on there, the file is pretty huge.. See and let me know if you find anything worth noting. Let me know. Thanks. https://docs.google.com/a/buffalo.edu/document/d/1hN-V0qL2qtzUtRCKnaslUweN62G3mxLrusM0fjI18L4/edit

Comment: @Nanda, I don't have access to the google doc, but in any case it's probably better to ask a new question and copy / paste the logcat into a code block.