# No such method getITelephony to disconnect Call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i want to disconnect outgoing call in ICS.

My issue is first of all I am not getting the broadcast in IC` in Gingerbread it is working fine and blocking the calls but in ICS its not Broadcasting.

for BroadCast I created a service and in that I am getting BroadCast of `PHONE_STATE` in ICS also but when i try to disconnect call I am getting error of

```
NO such method name 'getITelephony'
```

in ICS call is not disconnecting.

I am using following code to disconnect call using the BroadCast...

```
try{
       TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       Class c = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
       Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
       m.setAccessible(true);
       ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony)m.invoke(manager);
       telephony.endCall();
  } catch(Exception e){
       Log.d("",e.getMessage());
  }
```

[AndroidMaifest.xml](http://pastebin.com/4D46n2WM)

[PhonecallStateBroadcastReceiver.java](http://pastebin.com/kAzrWvaD)

with packgename of `package com.android.internal.telephony;`

`ITelephony.aidl`

```
interface ITelephony 
{
    boolean endCall();
    void answerRingingCall();
    void silenceRinger();
}
```

Comment: i am getting same problem in google nexus

Answer (score 2):

1) Download this class : [ITelephony](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java/?v=source&disposition=attachment)

2) Add this class.java in your project in package: com.android.internal.telephony

3) Add this permission in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And this receiver in application balise :

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

4) Create CallReceiver class :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ITelephony telephonyService = getTeleService(context);
    if(telephonyService!=null) {
        try {
            String numberCall = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.i("TAG", "CALL NUM: " + numberCall);
            if(numberCall.equals(TEST_NUMBER)) {
                telephonyService.endCall();
                Toast.makeText(context, "END CALL: " + numberCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("TAG", "END CALL");
            } else {
                Log.i("TAG", "ACCEPT CALL");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("TAG", "CATCH CALL");
        }
    }
}

private ITelephony getTeleService(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Method m = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        return (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can also download ITelephony.aidl here -> https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.aidl

Comment: Is there a way to direct call to voice mail?

Answer (score 1):

use of reflection to get access to "getITelephony" won't work in Android 2.3+

Reference:

http://hive-mind.org/android-call-blocking

[How do you programmatically end a call on 2.3+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054348/how-do-you-programmatically-end-a-call-on-2-3)

Comment: i know that it is not working that's why i had posted this question and the other link I already checked its also giving me same response...

Comment: then ur question should be modified appropriately to request the alternative solution

Comment: but in that answer it is mentioned that `silenceRinger() is not working but endCall() is just fine`

Comment: yup. Just I have provided the reference for what I said not for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Class c = Class.forName("android.telephony.TelephonyManager"); this will solve your problem for Android 2.3+