# how to control the calling activity in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

My application need to control the calling activity.I had use Itelephony aidl but it is not working in the real device.i had search lot of sights but they are all using ITelephony aidl.
my question is how to end the call programattically that is compatible with all the release.
I am using the object from the following method execute end call..

```
protected Object getITelephony(final Context context)
        throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException,
        IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException,
        IllegalAccessException
    {
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final Method getITelephony
                = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        if (!getITelephony.isAccessible()) {
            getITelephony.setAccessible(true);
        }
        return getITelephony.invoke(tm);

    }
```

Comment: Since the ITelephony.aidl approach is a hack to get around feeble attempts by Google to not provide this capability, you might have a hard time (read: be unable) finding a solution that works "with all the release", particularly if you're finding that this hack isn't that solution.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This is exactly the kind of thing that the API is designed to prevent you from doing.

Answer (score 0):

use of reflection to get access to "getITelephony" won't work in Android 2.3+

Reference:

http://hive-mind.org/android-call-blocking

[How do you programmatically end a call on 2.3+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054348/how-do-you-programmatically-end-a-call-on-2-3)

See this links may this helps you... as ITelephony is not working above API Level 2.3.

Comment: above 2.3 `ITelephony` not working you can not disconnect call and there is one option to pass on flight mode...

Comment: You cannot programmatically turn on airplane mode in recent versions.