# permission MODIFY_PHONE_STATE doesnot work

Tags: java, android, callblocking

i am working on call blocking app for android 2.2
this permission does not work for me

```
android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE
```

and it gives the following error

```
Permission is only granted to system apps
```

will my app work without this permission ???
or any other solution..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [How to grant MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission for apps ran on Gingerbread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread)

From that page:

*A change was checked in by David Brown that limits the use of the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission to system apps. System apps are either*

1. *Pre-installed into a system folder on the ROM*
2. *Compiled by a manufacturer using their security certificate*

In other words, you can't use that permission.

Comment: Thanks Bojan.. but my app crashes when it receives a call on emulator.

Comment: You can set permission but it souldn't work. If you have Android <= 2.2 it will work, but no later.

Comment: i am working on android 2.2 .but still it does not  allow MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission ..