# Enable/Disable Data mobile programmatically - NO ROOT

Tags: android

I'm trying to `enable/disable` data mobile in specific moments. I've tried it on `MotoG 4.4.2 (Rooted)` with it I had no problem to do this, but when I've tried it on `Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime 4.4.4 (No Root)` it doesn't work, also I've tried it on `Samsung Galaxy S3 4.3 (No Root)` but it worked.

1. MotoG Worked -- **WHY?** -- ROOT Acces
2. Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime didn't work -- **WHY?** -- I think it doesn't work because when I try to do it manually I've to accept a dialog that I want to lose data connectivity, and I think this is the problem because it doesn't work.
3. Samsung Galaxy S3 worked -- **WHY?** -- I think it worked because the user put "Don't show me again" and user accepted it before.

The code that I'm trying is :

```
public void GetDataConnectionAPI() {
    this.context.getApplicationContext();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
            (TelephonyManager) this.context.getApplicationContext().
                    getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        telephonyManagerClass = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
        Method getITelephonyMethod = telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
        ITelephonyStub = getITelephonyMethod.invoke(telephonyManager);
        ITelephonyClass = Class.forName(ITelephonyStub.getClass().getName());

        dataConnSwitchmethod_OFF =
                ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("disableDataConnectivity");
        dataConnSwitchmethod_ON = ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("enableDataConnectivity");
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then I enable/disable the data with this method :

```
public void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field connectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    connectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object connectivityManager = connectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class connectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(connectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = connectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connectivityManager, enabled);

}
```

When I want to Enable I call this method :

```
public void EnableMobileData(){
    try {
        setMobileDataEnabled(context, true);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On my Manifest I put

```
<!-- 3g uses-permisions-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I wonder if it's any possibility to avoid this dialog or just accept it programmatically..

I've read [Bojan Kogoj answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14536363/4385913) that sais that I've to :

> - Pre-installed into a system folder on the ROM
> - Compiled by a manufacturer using their security certificate

But I'm wondering if is any other way to do this.

Comment: *why, why, why* Because you are using not public API...

Comment: I know `TelephonyManager` is not public API but what I can use if I don't use it=

Comment: I've tried it without `TelephonyManager` and it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission is not guaranteed to work in all cases. By default it is a system-level permission, so it will only work on devices whose manufacturers have enabled it.

Similarly, methods like `getITelephony()` are device/manufacturer-specific, and there is no way to get the name of the methods for doing so on every device.

Unfortunately there is no guaranteed way to do this.

Comment: Okay... I'll investigate about it, because I've found some methods that works on any API versions but not on new API... (5.0.1)