# Block/Hide incoming calls in Android

Tags: android

First of all, let me warn you that i'm a beginner Android programmer.

I'm looking for a way to either block calls entirely or hide the default incoming call screen, i tried using the ITelephony.aidl but it seems that android no longer allows some of the permissions required by some of the methods.

I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/9462119/2458443 but failed to implement it, maybe some one can help me do it or explain the method in a more comprehensive manner.

Thx.

Comment: What permissions were missing? Did you put these permissions in your manifest? What do you mean by "failed  to implement it"? Were there any errors? I believe that if you edit your question and add code snippets of what exactly you were trying to accomplish and the results you got, we'll be able to help you better