# Programatically receiving a call and turning on speaker

Tags: android

Is it possible to receive a call and turn on the speaker programmatically in android?
Went through many question on stack overflow and google but was not satisfied. Even in [AutoAnswer](https://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java)
the speaker mode is not working in Jelly Bean. Any help guys?

This is what I get in logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10212 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.answerRingingCall(ITelephony.java:798)
    at com.example.thu.Callclass$Calllistener.onSensorChanged(Callclass.java:144)
    at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:250)
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @RobertHarvey : I meant even if I select Speaker in AutoAnswer, it receives the call but is unable to turn on the speaker.

Comment: Could you post some source code?

Comment: @nOiAd: +1, but there's already some code to look at in the link provided.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : Error log updated.

Comment: Ah, enlightenment.  `Neither user 10212 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I have added MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission. I think this is a system level permission that is not accessible to apps. But there are apps on the playstore that can modify Phone State!!

Comment: +1 to the question. Even i am facing the same problem. I have tried the Itelephony api, but it is no longer usable. Then I have tried the code of autanswer, but the problem is speakerphone is not getting activated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this permission to your manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: I have added MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission. I think this is a system level permission that is not accessible to apps. But there are apps on the playstore that can modify Phone State!!

Comment: yes. I have added this. But it is no longer accessible by apps. This is a system level permission now. What i want to now is whether there is an alternative to this? Because there are some apps in the play stor that does these tasks.

Comment: @vish Yes, but it only actually _works_ on Froyo and older devices. [Since Gingerbread it no longer works except for system apps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4715250/1068283).