# android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" not worked properly

Tags: android, android-permissions

I had already added this permission in my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```

But it will not give me permission to cut the incoming call, I can receive the call.when I'm try to cut the call it give me

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10037 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.
```

I have gone through so many blogs,but none of work.
In some of the emulator its working fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4720069/2107464

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread

Answer (score 1):

MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is a system-only permission, so you can not access or use this permission in your app,
[Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread)!

Answer (score 1):

Place your app in the `/system/priv-app` folder instead of `/system/app`, when using Android 4.3 or higher.