# Android permission modify phone state

Tags: android

i worked on android call blocker  app . their i have an error 
Modify phone State error  permission is granted to system app only. 
can any body help me about this error

Comment: Answer to your problem is already here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread

Comment: Modify phone state was down since Gingerbread. Best approach is to do this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9701604/1398731