# How to get permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE in Android 6?

Tags: android, permissions

Exists any way to allow apps to get android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE in Android 6? Even with root?

In versions prior to Android 6 this permission can be obtained copying APK to /system, but I have run this in Android 6 and the permission wasn't obtained.

Also, the permission can't be manually granted to the app due to isn't at the listed permissions for the app (in apps -> all -> APP -> permissions)
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread

Comment: Isn't the same question that you are refering to