# System Permission MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, permissions

I am working on one project on that project i have to work with the below permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

as per below link :-
[How to grant MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission for apps ran on Gingerbread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread)

this permission is system permission not used by other application but i want to know is there any other way to achive this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

`MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` is a system-only permission, you could root device and put your app in `/system/priv-app` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance i was having security exception but after your solution i am not getting security exception but my method `setSimPowerStateForSlot` is still not working. Any idea? Thanks in advance